# Store .txt filenames in array on Android

Tags: android, file, filenames, text-files, sd-card

I would like to store only `.txt` filenames from a specific dir (let's say: `/sdcard/docs/`) into an `String` array.

Example:
In `/sdcard/docs/` there are 5 files: `foo.txt`, `bar.jpg`, `foofoo.txt`, `loool.png` and     `foobar.txt`. I would like to get array with contents: `"foo.txt", "foofoo.txt", "foobar.txt"`

How could I do it?

Comment: Just search for "java FileFilter" in the search box at the top of this page.  You will get tons of examples on how to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List all files:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list%28%29

or

List with filter:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29

Just pass your path to the File constructor, and call one of the above methods on it.